# Push-Pull DC converter - resonance in the waveform

Tags: transformer, power-electronics, dc, dc-dc-converter, switching-losses

I'm building 48v to 200v Push-Pull DC converter.
And now I'm close to finishing the project, but when I checked the waveform on the transformer I discovered that it looks like this:

[image]
(on this picture waveform is stretched)

It has some kind of resonance in the middle of the off stage in the square wave.
When this picture was taken converter was powered from a lab power supply at 50V, and a 100w light bulb was connected to the output. The power supply was showing about 1.85~1.90A, and considering that it is a 230V bulb supplied with 210V it doesn't seem to have much effect on the efficiency.

Does anyone know what can cause this?

This picture shows waveform with correct proportions, time base is 10us and converter is running at about 31.5~32kHz, so cycle has about 31,75~31,25us.

[image]

This is how my converter looks like:

[image]

This is schematic of my converter:

[image]

It is a typical push-pull converter.

I'm not sure about coil inductance because I don't have device to measure it.
The bottom half of the schematic (part with ATTINY) isn't finished yet.

Comment: Nice layout! But I'm afraid you'll have to provide a schematic to proceed with this question. Include transformer and inductor design drawings / specs as well, if possible.

Comment: What time base is the scope running at? What’s your switching frequency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite typical for SMPS topologies that leave the transformer's primary "open" during part of their operating cycle. It's nothing to worry about.

In particular, this happens when the secondary current drops to zero during each cycle, or in other words, it happens when the converter enters discontinuous conduction mode (DCM).

As long as current flows through the output inductors, the secondary winding of the transformer is essentially shorted through the full-bridge rectifier that's connected to it. However, once the current through those inductors drops to zero, the rectifier stops conducting. Since the transformer is also not being driven by the primary transistors during the off phase, both its primary and secondary are now completely disconnected. As a result, the magnetizing inductance of the transformer can resonate with the parasitic inter-winding capacitance, causing a low-frequency sinusoidal oscillation.

The points in time at which these various phases happen in the cycle are easily spotted in the oscilloscope trace you provided. Here's a crude GIMP sketch of what's happening:

[image: GIMP sketch showing the transformer's secondary current]

The energy available to sustain this oscillation is quite low - it's essentially just a small electric field spooking around in the inter-winding capacitance of the transformer - so this is not going to damage anything.

There are a few things you can do about it:

- Ignore it.
- Increase the secondary smoothing inductor's value to prevent the converter from entering discontinuous conduction mode. This lowers the ripple current.
- Add a snubber network at the transformer's secondary.

The snubber network would look something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffLsWV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You'll have to experiment with the values a bit, the provided numbers are just an educated guess. You can calculate the power dissipation in the resistor as:

```
Psnubber = 2 * f * C * V²
```

For `f=32kHz, C=1nF, V=210V`, this comes out to about 2.8 Watts.

The snubber network should also be able to get rid of some of the ringing that you've got on the turn-on edges.